# Reducing the quality of incoming video in Skype?

Tags: video, skype

Is it possible to reduce the quality of *incoming* video when making a video call in Skype? I want to be able to see the person I'm speaking with less clearly.

The reason I want it is because the other person is... Hard to look at.

Comment: No offence but... WHY? XD

Comment: I'm with BloodPhilia here.  Do you want the other user to be somewhat obscured for security reasons?  Is it a bandwidth limitation?

Comment: You need to specify your operating system, but you might search (this site, the general web) for keyword "Bandwidth Throttle".

Comment: You know you can use Skype for voice-only calls, too... (If necessary, pretend your computer has issues with showing the video.)

Answer (score 2):

With Skype you get what the other side sends.

You will need to ask the other person to lower their video quality, maybe using bandwidth as the excuse.